# Execute Grails Command in BuildConfig GAnt closure

Tags: grails, ant, gant

I want to execute a Grails command (grails doc) in the `BuildConfig.groovy` to do some stuff before the war is packaged:

```
grails.war.resources = { stagingDir, args ->
    // call some ant tasks
}
```

How can I execute a Grails command in this closure?